# Multiple Google homes one WiFi

Tags: google-home, google-assistant

What is the point in assigning your Google home devices to a home?

I have 6 Google devices, the Google one with a screen in the kitchen, and 4 dotted around the house. These are all on a home called home.

The 6th is in my bedroom but I have set it to a second home 2

Both homes on the same WiFi

If I try and broadcast a message from the device on home 2 it says it can't as there are no other devices

I can go to any of the other devices in the house broadcast and it then broad casts to all devices on the WiFi including the one on home 2

So what's the point in being able to have multiple homes on one WiFi? I guess I'd I had a second device on the home 2 it would probably braodcast to all devices on both homes on the same network.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a point to having them on the same network (in the same physical building).

The implication of the feature is more for it you have multiple locations (e.g. home and office or holiday home) so you can have them work with the same account but organise the devices logically.

Answer (score 1):

There is not, because that is not its intended purpose. It is supposed to be for different setups. I have three "homes" with Google Wifi; our city flat, our rural country house and a rental unit by the country house. They are separate units and will then get different settings for all manners of things, so I can control both Wifis and different Chromecast setups from the same app.